# loop is just inserting the last row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to C# and I'm coding a web site in witch I need to insert multiple data in a row inside my database. some of the data will be set automatically and the others from form. here is my controller part:

```
public ActionResult chekout()
{
    return View(new Commande());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult chekout([Bind(Include = "Id_commande,prenom,nom,Adresse,telephone,Email,produit,prix,cart")] Commande commande)
{
    var panier = from Panier in db.Paniers
    select Panier;
    var userEmail = this.User.Identity.Name;

    panier = panier.Where(x => x.user.Contains(userEmail));
    Panier[] pa = panier.ToArray();
    List<Commande> list = new List<Commande>();

    for (int i = 0; i < pa.Length; i++)
    {
        commande.Id_commande = db.Commandes.Max(I => I.Id_commande) + 1;
        commande.produit = pa[i].Quantite + " X " + pa[i].nom_produit;
        commande.prix = int.Parse(pa[i].prix) * pa[i].Quantite;
        commande.Email = userEmail;
        list.Add(commande);
    }

    db.Commandes.AddRange(list);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("order_complete", "Home");
}
```

and this is my view part:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.prenom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.prenom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "veuillez remplir ce champ" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.prenom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "veuillez remplir ce champ" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Adresse, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adresse, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "veuillez remplir ce champ" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Adresse, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.telephone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "veuillez remplir ce champ" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.telephone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cart, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "veuillez remplir ce champ" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cart, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type = "submit" value="Commander" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I do not get error  but I don't know why but it just adds the last row 
so if anyone can help me I would be grateful.

Comment: Can you debug and see what you are getting in  `pa`

Comment: i am sorry what do you mean by debug

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same `commande` object repeatedly in the loop, you need to instantiate new object commande in every iteration. You need to add the first line in loop below, please do change the variable name "commande" if a same name exist at class level.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pa.Length; i++)
    {
        Commande commande = new Commande ();
        commande.Id_commande = db.Commandes.Max(I => I.Id_commande) + 1;
        commande.produit = pa[i].Quantite + " X " + pa[i].nom_produit;
        commande.prix = int.Parse(pa[i].prix) * pa[i].Quantite;
        commande.Email = userEmail;
        list.Add(commande);
    }
```

Comment: i tried to add commande= new commande() inside for loop but i got an error